Riverpod Flutter State: Struggling with Inconsistent State Behavior
I'm currently working on a Flutter app using Riverpod, and I've encountered an issue with state management that I don't understand. To debug, I simplified my code to this example, which you can run to follow along.
Here is the simplified code you can run it if you know about Riverpod Code Generation:
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'main.g.dart';

@riverpod
class RandomNumber extends _$RandomNumber {
  @override
  String build() {
    print('im in build in quote provider');
    return Random().nextInt(5).toString();
  }
}

final giveBoolProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);

void main() {
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final num = ref.watch(randomNumberProvider); // comment this
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            ref.read(giveBoolProvider.notifier).update((state) {
              return !state;
            });
          },
          child: ref.watch(giveBoolProvider) == true
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [Text(num), Text(num)], // comment this
                  //  children: [Text(ref.watch(randomNumberProvider)), Text(ref.watch(randomNumberProvider))], // uncomment this
                )
              : const Text('giveBool is false'),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}

Problem:
When I press the button, a random number is shown. If I press the button again, nothing happens. Pressing the button a third time shows the same random number because the state of randomNumberProvider did not change. This is the expected behavior.
However, when I:
Comment out the lines marked with // comment this.
Uncomment the lines marked with // uncomment this.
The build method of randomNumberProvider is called every time, even though I haven't explicitly changed its state. This results in a new random number being generated each time the button is pressed.
In both scenarios, the widget's build method is called. I'm unsure why the state behaves differently in these two cases.
Could someone explain what I'm missing here and why there's a difference in behavior between the two scenarios?
Thank you!

Stop using StateProvider.  Not saying that's your problem, but it's a good start.  Also your provider isn't keep alive.  You should add instrumentation with .onDispose to see when it is being destroyed.  That might give you more clues about how often it gets rebuilt.

Short answer: The provider is being watched conditionally in the second scenario, and it's an auto-disposing provider.

Explanation:
The random number provider is an auto-disposing provider, as it's the default configuration for generated providers.
In the first scenario, ref.watch(randomNumberProvider) is always called on every build, so the provider is never destroyed, as it's still being listened to, resulting in its data being cached.
In the second scenario, ref.watch is used conditionally based on the value exposed by giveBoolProvider, which causes the random number provider to get destroyed whenever giveBoolProvider exposes false. The next time giveBoolProvider exposes true, ref.watch(randomNumberProvider) will be called again, so the provider execute its build method and generate a new number.

I got it thank you, but in this way the solution will be putting @Riverpod(keepalive:true) annotation before RandomNumber class, to not dispose the provider when the provider expose true false, right? but it did not work for me to put that anotation, what is the problem here?

am I right? please read the comment above
